# How to create a button with several polygon drawables inside (in LibGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Is there some easy way to create a [Button](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) in **LibGDX** that contains several polygon drawables inside.

For example when the simple [Button](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) can be pictured like:
[image: simple button]

and advanced expected button like that:

[image: advanced button]

And in my case following conditions must be met:

1. The Object must extends [Button](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) class.
2. Separated polygons (circle and triangle in pic) must have one common behavior - same up, down, hover styles, same click listeners ect. (for example when user hover circle the triangle and circle change color to green)

Actually it must have the absolutely same behavior as button with one polygon, just imagine that circle and triangle is one polygon, instead of separated ones.

The one way I figured out is to extend [PolygonRegionDrawable](http://dermetfan.net/libgdx-utils/javadoc/net/dermetfan/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/PolygonRegionDrawable.html), but to make it drawn correctly I need to override almost all methods from [Drawable](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/Drawable.html) and [TransformDrawable](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/TransformDrawable.html), is there any easier way to do that?

Maybe there can be found some DrawableGroup or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think theres an easy way to make this work, here are some options.

`Button` is a `Table`, you can add stuff to it.

```
Button button = new Button(skin);
Image img = new Image(...); // insert polygon 1 here
img.setPostion(...); // offset so its in correct position in the button
button.addActor(img);
// add more stuff
```

Sadly this doesnt handle various state changes, like over etc. You would need to keep track of the added stuff and change them as button changes.

Other option is to make the polygons into single image. 
Thats quite tricky, you would draw them into `FrameBufferObject` in correct places and make a textures out of that. Then use that texture for `Drawable` for the button style. Reapet for each state you want to handle. Packing them into and atlas would be optimal for perfomace reasons. A ton of texture switches is not great.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It seems I am only one person who need such behavior. As for me it is strange that only I need button with two drawables.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reach such functionality I have implemented two additional classes that may assume a list of Drawables to draw it like only one.

So I just mention it here, I hope it may be useful for people who want to implement the same behavior.

An abstract class that assumes list of drawables and related coordinates in format:

```
[drawable1X, drawable1Y, drawable2X, drawable2Y, ..., drawableNX, drawableNY]
```

**BulkBaseDrawable:**

```
abstract class BulkBaseDrawable implements Drawable {

    Array<Drawable> drawables;
    private float leftWidth, rightWidth, topHeight, bottomHeight, minWidth, minHeight, leftX, bottomY, rightX, topY;

    BulkBaseDrawable(Drawable[] drawables,
                     float... vertices) {
        this.infos = new Array<>(drawables.length);
        init(drawables, vertices);
    }

    @Override
    public float getLeftWidth() {
        return leftWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLeftWidth(float leftWidth) {
        this.leftWidth = leftWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public float getRightWidth() {
        return rightWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRightWidth(float rightWidth) {
        this.rightWidth = rightWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public float getTopHeight() {
        return topHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTopHeight(float topHeight) {
        this.topHeight = topHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public float getBottomHeight() {
        return bottomHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBottomHeight(float bottomHeight) {
        this.bottomHeight = bottomHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinWidth() {
        return minWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMinWidth(float minWidth) {
        this.minWidth = minWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinHeight() {
        return minHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMinHeight(float minHeight) {
        this.minHeight = minHeight;
    }

    void init(Drawable[] drawables, float[] vertices) {
        initInfo(drawables, vertices);
        initEdges();
        initSize();
    }

    private void initInfo(Drawable[] drawables, float[] vertices) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            infos.add(Info.builder()
                    .x(vertices[i])
                    .y(vertices[i + 1])
                    .width(drawable.getMinWidth())
                    .height(drawable.getMinHeight())
                    .drawable(drawable)
                    .build());
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    private void initSize() {
        minHeight = topY - bottomY;
        minWidth = rightX - leftX;
    }

    private void initEdges() {
        topY = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        rightX = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        bottomY = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        leftX = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        int topI = 0;
        int rightI = 0;
        int bottomI = 0;
        int leftI = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.size; i++) {
            Info info = infos.get(i);
            if (info.y + info.height > topY) {
                topY = info.y + info.height;
                topI = i;
            }
            if (info.x + info.width > rightX) {
                rightX = info.x + info.width;
                rightI = i;
            }
            if (info.y < bottomY) {
                bottomY = info.y;
                bottomI = i;
            }
            if (info.x < leftX) {
                leftX = info.x;
                leftI = i;
            }
        }
        Drawable top = infos.get(topI).drawable;
        Drawable right = infos.get(rightI).drawable;
        Drawable bottom = infos.get(bottomI).drawable;
        Drawable left = infos.get(leftI).drawable;
        leftWidth = left.getLeftWidth();
        rightWidth = right.getRightWidth();
        topHeight = top.getTopHeight();
        bottomHeight = bottom.getBottomHeight();
    }

    static class Info {

        float x, y, width, height;
        Drawable drawable;

        static InfoBuilder builder() {
            return new InfoBuilder();
        }

        static class InfoBuilder {

            float x, y, width, height;
            Drawable drawable;

            InfoBuilder x(float x) {
                this.x = x;
                return this;
            }

            InfoBuilder y(float y) {
                this.y = y;
                return this;
            }

            InfoBuilder width(float width) {
                this.width = width;
                return this;
            }

            InfoBuilder height(float height) {
                this.height = height;
                return this;
            }

            InfoBuilder drawable(Drawable drawable) {
                this.drawable = drawable;
                return this;
            }

            Info build() {
                return new Info(x, y, width, height, drawable);
            }
        }

        public Info(float x, float y, float width, float height, Drawable drawable) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.drawable = drawable;
        }
    }
}
```

And actually implementation **BulkRegionDrawable:**

```
public class BulkRegionDrawable extends BulkBaseDrawable {

    public BulkRegionDrawable(Drawable[] drawables, float[] vertices) {
        super(drawables, vertices);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch,
                     float x,
                     float y,
                     float width,
                     float height) {
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.size; i++) {
            Info info = infos.get(i);
            float yK = info.height / getMinHeight();
            float xK = info.width / getMinWidth();
            info.drawable.draw(
                    batch,
                    x + (info.x * width) / getMinWidth(),
                    y + (info.y * height) / getMinHeight(),
                    width * xK,
                    height * yK);
        }
    }
}
```